Why Brahmins are immune to many punishments in Dharmashastras
I want to know why Brahmins were immune to many punishments in dharmashastras which are indeed heinous doesn't this mean a Brahmin can do anything he/she wants? Once again I am not 100% against these texts I find beauty in them, but I need understanding. Currently, I have heard that Shastras wonder how such a person of high birth would murder someone, but that simply doesn't answer the question especially when Brahmins who do not commit to their duty still get some privileges ordinary Brahmins get. Also while I understand that punishments may be limited on upper-class individuals due to their rarity ie if one doctor was left in the US he would be precious and hence some crimes he may not be held accountable for that still isn't just it is simply a natural occurrence. I want a greater why. Please answer based on various Dharmashastras, Nitishastras, Dharmasutras and Bhashyas by Dharmacharyas.
